# How to audit common userid usages in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, audit-logging

As per audit requirement, I need to track and monitor common userid source and usages.

We have some dba common userid's which are attached with different owner roles. As per audit requirement, I need to track and monitor who the individual is using common userid and activities?

I can see SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGES views are giving me some information.

```
QUERY_HISTORY ==> Query from user and Session ID
SESSIONS ==> Session ID and Login Event Id
LOGIN_HISTORY ==> Event ID and Client IP
```

But here I can get up to client IP address information only. I can't find which is client side userid. If I get this information then it some way to tag it to individual user.

Any idea, how can I get this information?

Thank you,
Shrini S

Comment: In each of those views there is a column named `user_name`. Isn't this what you're looking for?

Comment: So, you have multiple users using the same login information and you want to be able to later tell who the users are?  That's the reason to have separate userids.  Snowflake has no idea who the users are that are leveraging a userid, so you should create separate userids for each user.

Comment: Yes. That's true that and we are going with separate userid but there are some Service userid's which are occasionally used by DBA's to do some adhoc tasks. I need to audit those usages.

Comment: Why not separate those, as well?

Comment: Every user should really have their own account. If you have service accounts that multiple automated process use then you can use query tagging to differentiate them. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#query-tag